# KineticJS Example Needed: Gradient Fill with Rect?

Tags: kineticjs, linear-gradients

I haven't gotten gradient fill working with KineticJS rect objects yet. Here's my code:

```
var width = 500;
var height = 20;
y = y + 20;
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: centerOfCanvasX - (width / 2),
    y: y,
    stroke: '#000',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: '#fff',
    width: width,
    height: height,
    fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [10, 0],
    fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [400, 0],
    fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 300, 'yellow']
});
mainLayer.add(rect);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like problem is here:

```
fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 300, 'yellow']
```

Values shoud be from 0 to 1.

```
fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'red', 1, 'yellow']
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/lavrton/DVzeE/